# JQuery $.each loop reorders my array when using json_encode from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

**PHP:**

```
 $arr[0] = 'A';
 $arr['C'] = 'C';
 $arr[10] = 'B';

 echo json_encode($arr);
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $.each(result, function(i, item) {
    console.log(i + " => " + item);
 });
```

Desired Output:

```
   0 => A
   C => C
   10 => B
```

Instead I Get:

```
   0 => A
   10 => B
   C => C
```

how can i prevent it to re-order my array without modifying the PHP code or restructuring the array?

Edit:

when ajax is called in response headers using firebug it seems to be in correct order:

```
"0":"A","C":"C","10":"B"
```

however when I do console.log inside $.each loop its re-ordered

Comment: That's no array, that's an [object](http://json.org/). And object keys are not ordered. If you need to preserve order, use an array.

Comment: but how do i do it when i need to pass it from PHP to Javascript ?

Comment: I just told you: use an array - only numeric keys, and iterate them with a `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loop

Comment: not an option since its not up to me. The array has non-numeric keys :(

Comment: Then you can do nothing but: Extract the keys from the object and sort() them in some way (if their order is known) or manually parse the JSON string, using arrays instead of objects. And tell the one who is responsible for the JSON that objects in JSON are specified to be unordered…

Answer (score 3):

Your `$arr` is an object, not an array and the keys aren't indexed nor ordered.

You don't have guarantee in JavaScript about the iteration order on object properties, only the indexed keys (i.e. integer keys) of arrays.

To iterate over a plain object, `$.each` uses the standard `for..in` construct on which [the MDN precises that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an
>   arbitrary order

If you want to keep arbitrary key-value ordered, you should store both in a proper array :

```
  var arr = [];
  arr.push({key:0, value:'A'});
  arr.push({key:'C', value:'C'});
  arr.push({key:10, value:'B'});
```

Comment: but im doing it on PHP side how can i do this using PHP?

Comment: @GGio: The code above creates an empty array and adds some items. You don't know how to do that in PHP? Why not read the manual?

Comment: I don't remember how to do that in PHP. If somebody wants to complete my answer, I made it CW.

Comment: @Jon if you look at my code it has an array that contains exact keys and values but the problem is once used $.each loop on it when passed to Javascript it re-orders it.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't "reorder" it : the encoding of such an object in JSON isn't ordered.

Comment: @GGio: I have read everything on this page, and both dystroy and Bergi have given an accurate answer to your question. But you need to work a little yourself.